# Show that $α$ is a perfect square in the quadratic integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

**Question:**

Suppose that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ is a UFD, and $α$ is an integer in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ so that $α$ and $\barα$ have no common factor, but $N(α)$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb Z$. How can I show that $α$ is a perfect square in the quadratic integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$?

**What I have Done:**

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly but if  $\alpha$ and  $\bar{\alpha}$ have no common factor, then $\alpha=\pi_{1}\pi_{2}\cdots\pi_{k}$ and  $\bar{\alpha}=\pi'_{1}\pi'_{2}\cdots\pi'_{j}$ where $ \pi_{i}$ and  $\pi'_{i} $ are prime in  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. But $N(\alpha) = \alpha\bar{\alpha}=\pi_{1}\pi_{2}\cdots\pi_{k}\pi'  _{1}\pi'_{2}\cdots\pi'_{j}=n^{2}$ where  $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Somehow I need to show that $\alpha=\beta^{2}$ where  $\beta$ is a quadratic integer in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ (i.e.,  $\alpha$ is a perfect square in the quadratic integers in  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$)

Comment: @abiessu I added to my question.

Comment: It seems to me like $\gcd(\alpha, \overline\alpha) = 1$ is incompatible with $N(\alpha)$ being a perfect square. Can you give a concrete example, in, say, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte, how about $3\pm4i$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$?

Comment: I think your conjecture is false, see my comment below. But I gave you an up-arrow, because I think the conjecture is pleasing.

Comment: @Lubin That's an excellent example, one I should've thought of more readily.

Answer (score 2):

[I guess you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ instead of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$. The latter is a field, and it's not really meaningful to talk about unique factorisation in a field.]

You can complete your strategy by proving that (with your notation) the $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j'$ are different.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be a UFD and $x$, $y$ be two coprime elements such that $xy$ is associated to a square. Then $x$ and $y$ are associated to squares.

**Proof.** If $x = \epsilon\, p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$ and $y = \eta \,q_1^{f_1}\cdots q_s^{f_s}$ are their decompositions in irreducible elements, (with $\epsilon, \eta \in A^\times$) then the $p_i$ and the $q_j$ are disjoint (because $x$ and $y$ are coprime) and the decomposition of $xy$ is then $xy = \epsilon\,\eta\, p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_r^{e_r}q_1^{f_1}\cdots q_s^{f_s}$.

Because $xy$ is a associated to a square, all the $e_i$ and all the $f_j$ are even integers, which proves that
$$x = \epsilon\, \left( p_1^{e_1/2} \cdots p_r^{e_r/2}\right)^2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad y = \eta \,\left( q_1^{f_1/2} \cdots q_s^{f_s/2}\right)^2.$$

This answers your question.

And to answer Alonso del Arte's concern: $\alpha = (1+2i)^2 \in \mathbb Q(i)$ works. Then $\alpha$ and $\overline{\alpha} = (1-2i)^2$ are coprime ($1 \pm 2i$ are irreducible elements and they aren't associated because $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$ are the only units) and $\alpha \overline{\alpha} = \left( (1+2i)(1-2i) \right)^2 = 25.$ You can do such examples every time a prime number $p$ (5 in this example) [splits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions?oldformat=true#Example_.E2.80.94_the_Gaussian_integershttp://) in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

Comment: But I’m a little worried about units. Even for $i\in\Bbb Z[i]$, you have an integer that’s (naturally) relatively prime to its conjugate, but is not a perfect square. This seems to me to apply to the integer $i(1+2i)^2$ just as well.

Comment: I think that the exercise has to be modified to mean: if $N(\alpha)$ is a square, then $\alpha$ is associated to a square. Otherwise, any time you have nonsquare units $\eta \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt d]^\times$, you will have exactly the same problem: $N(\alpha) = N(\eta \alpha)$ but at most one of $\alpha$ and $\eta \alpha$ can be a square).

Comment: Right you are, I’m in complete agreement. The moral of the story is that a good conjecture may need to be modified to take in phenomena more perfectly.

Comment: A second moral is that when you talk about divisibility, the natural things to consider are often elements *up to association*. Anyway, as soon as you advance in the field, you will think less and less about individual elements and more and more about ideals. As the principal ideal $(x)$ contains exactly the same information as $x$ up to association, this moral becomes more and more evident.